# Adapter is not showing anything

Tags: java, android, gridview, adapter

I am doing a small quiz game where I have a Gridview displaying answers using a custom adapter that extends from BaseAdapter.

The problem is that for some reason, anything is displayed in the gridView when executed, 
here goes the code:

Edit: The entire GitHub project: 
https://github.com/Marc-Ferrer-Castillo/ABP

**Quiz XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#000000">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btniniciar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/joc" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/inicio"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/sortir" />

    //Textview para las preguntas
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pregunta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Blanco"
        android:layout_marginTop="360dp"/>

    //GridView para las respuestas
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridRespuestas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="900dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Inflater XML layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/placeRespuesta"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Custom Adapter**

```
package com.example.joc;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;

public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {


    private List<Respuesta> respuestas;
    private Activity context;

    public Adaptador(Activity _context,List<Respuesta> _respuestas) {

        context = _context;
        respuestas = _respuestas;
    }



    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        CompleteListViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.place_respuesta, null);
            viewHolder = new CompleteListViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else {
            viewHolder = (CompleteListViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.mTVItem.setText(respuestas.get(position).getRespuesta());
        view.setTag(position);

        return view;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class CompleteListViewHolder {
        public TextView mTVItem;
        public CompleteListViewHolder(View base) {
            mTVItem = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.placeRespuesta);
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity where the Quiz is**

```
package com.example.joc;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Juego extends AppCompatActivity {
/*

 1. Recibimos la primera pregunta a mostrar con las variables:
    MainActivity.getPlanetaMostrado() y preguntaMostrada

 2. Filtrar las preguntas y guardarlas en una lista nueva

 3. Rellenar(); <-- Muestra la pregunta en el textview y sus respuestas en la gridview

 4. OnClick respuesta:
    4.1 Si hay más preguntas se muestra la siguiente y llamamos a rellenar()
    4.2 Si no hay más preguntas pasamos de planeta (si quedan)
*/
    private static int preguntaMostrada = 0;

    static List<Pregunta> preguntasFiltradas = new ArrayList<Pregunta>();

    public int getPreguntaMostrada() {
        return preguntaMostrada;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_juego);


        // Lista de planetas
        final List<Planeta> planetas = Importar.getPlanetas();

        filtrarPreguntas( planetas.get(MainActivity.getPlanetaMostrado()).getPreguntas() );

        cargarContenido();

        // Imagen Salir
        ImageView salir = findViewById(R.id.inicio);

        // Click en salir
        salir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Devuelve RESULT OK a la clase Contenido
                setResult(Contenido.RESULT_OK);

                // Cierra esta actividad
                finish();
            }
        });

        GridView gridRespuestas = findViewById(R.id.gridRespuestas);
        // Al pulsar sobre un item del grid
        gridRespuestas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if ( preguntaMostrada < preguntasFiltradas.size() ){

                    preguntaMostrada++;
                    cargarContenido();
                }
                else{
                    int planetaMostrado = MainActivity.getPlanetaMostrado();
                    planetaMostrado++;

                    if ( planetaMostrado < MainActivity.getUltimoPlaneta() ){

                        // Devuelve RESULT OK a la clase Dificultad
                        //setResult(Contenido.RESULT_FIRST_USER);

                        //Cierra esta actividad
                        finish();
                    }
                }


            }
        });




    }


    private void cargarContenido() {
        List<Respuesta> respuestas = preguntasFiltradas.get(preguntaMostrada).getRespuestas();

        TextView viewPregunta = findViewById(R.id.pregunta);
        GridView gridRespuestas = findViewById(R.id.gridRespuestas);

        viewPregunta.setText(preguntasFiltradas.get(preguntaMostrada).getPregunta());

        //Instancia nuestro adaptador personalizado
        Adaptador adaptador = new Adaptador(this, respuestas);

        gridRespuestas.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }

    private void filtrarPreguntas(List<Pregunta> preguntas) {

        // Dificultad de juego: Facil
        if (!Dificultad.dificultadSeleccionada){

            // Recorre la lista de preguntas
            for (int i = 0 ; i < preguntas.size() ; i++){

                // Si la pregunta es facil
                if (preguntas.get(i).isDificultad()){

                    // Se añade a la lista de preguntas filtradas
                    preguntasFiltradas.add( preguntas.get(i) );
                }
            }
        }
        //Dificultad de juego: Dificil
        else{

            // Recorre la lista de preguntas
            for (int i = 0 ; i <  preguntas.size() ; i++){

                // Si la pregunta es dificil
                if ( ! preguntas.get(i).isDificultad() ){

                    // Se añade a la lista de preguntas filtradas
                    preguntasFiltradas.add(preguntas.get(i) );
                }
            }
        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your adapter class your are not providing number of items in list to adapter instead default 0 is provided:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

Here you should return size of your list:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
  if(respuestas != null)
    return respuestas.size();
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to create adapter without using `ViewHolder` then first of app delete `CompleteListViewHolder` class. Then inside `getView`:

```
 View view = convertView;
if (view == null){
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.place_respuesta, null);
 }

        TextView  mTVItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.placeRespuesta);
        mTVItem.setText(respuestas.get(position).getRespuesta());

return view;
```

Comment: I filled the getCount() as you said and looks like the app is crashing when the activity containing the gridView shows up. I'm going to investigate

Comment: @Marc What is the crash report? Stack trace?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.joc.Contenido.onCreate(Contenido.java:36)

its this line: viewHolder = (CompleteListViewHolder) view.getTag();

Comment: I just followed a tutorial... All I want to do is setText to the layout TextView...
something like this:

TextView answer = findViewById(R.id.placeRespuesta);
 answer.setText(respuestas.get(position).getRespuesta());

I seems like I can' t use findViewById here

Comment: @Marc actually my bad you are doing that right. Are you sure that exception is not thrown on this line of code: `viewHolder.mTVItem.setText(respuestas.get(position).getRespuesta());`?

Comment: I commented that line and it crashes on: `viewHolder = (CompleteListViewHolder) view.getTag();`

Comment: Now I got this: `error: constructor CompleteListViewHolder in class Adaptador.CompleteListViewHolder cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: View
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length` How this would work without any viewHolder in order to place the text in every TextView?